# That's weird. Iframe fancybox's content is shown only for certains urls?

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I'm using iframes with fancybox 1.3.1 and works great but only for some urls.
If I put for example google.com everything is Ok, but with youtube.com the iframe fancybox is empty...???

A working example here (click on tab "date passate" and then on one of the google maps link on the top right column)
http://ragazzosemplice.com/live.html

A non working example: just click on the bubble "Video" (same web site a s above, just in the header) and then an empty fancybox appear, the missing link is a youtube profile...

I literally used the same syntax...
?????
Cheers

Comment: It asks for a username and password. I use fancybox with an iframe and I can confirm that it displays any url put into it. Might be some other issue

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by myself that youtube doesn't allow anymore to be inserted in iframes... :(
Thanks anyway